# Unable to delete persistent objects from Google App Engine datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, non-relational-database

I have 2 classes `AAA` and `BBB`, where `BBB` contains a field of `AAA` type.

When I call `makePersistent()` on 10 AAA and 10 BBB objects, the datastore ends up with 20 AAA objects and 10 BBB objects. I understand this is normal since GAE's datastore is non-relational.

However, when I try to `deletePersistentAll` using the following,

```
pm.newQuery(BBB.class).deletePersistentAll();
pm.newQuery(AAA.class).deletePersistentAll();
```

All BBB objects get removed as expected, but all 20 AAA objects remain. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Isolation and Consistency](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html#Isolation_and_Consistency)
The datastore's isolation level outside of transactions is closest to READ_COMMITTED.

These tests pass.

```
PersistenceManager pm = pmfInstance.getPersistenceManager();

// make 10 AAA objects
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pm.makePersistent(new AAA());
}

// make 10 BBB objects
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pm.makePersistent(new BBB(new AAA()));
}

// make sure we have 20 AAA's
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<AAA> aaa = (List<AAA>) pm.newQuery(AAA.class).execute();

assertEquals(20, aaa.size());

// make sure we have 10 BBB's
List<BBB> bbb = (List<BBB>) pm.newQuery(BBB.class).execute();

assertEquals(10, bbb.size());

// try to delete
pm.newQuery(BBB.class).deletePersistentAll();
bbb = (List<BBB>) pm.newQuery(BBB.class).execute();
assertEquals(0, bbb.size());

pm.newQuery(AAA.class).deletePersistentAll();
aaa = (List<AAA>) pm.newQuery(AAA.class).execute();
assertEquals(0, aaa.size());
assertEquals(0, bbb.size());
```